# QTcpSocket High frequency writes slows transfer rate

Tags: qt, tcp, streaming, latency

I'm working on a streaming app, I get a frame, encode it to h264 and then send it via tcp to the client, then the client receive the encoded frame, it decode it a display it. What I found is that, when calling several times the write method in smalls intervals of time, the transfer rate is considerably affected.

The interval time is between 12 ms and 17 ms, which is the time it take to grab a frame and encode it. In the client I am counting the time it takes from read one frame and another. Using 12/17 ms the time it takes to arrive to the client is ~400 ms. However, if I add a sleep in the writes, from lets say 12/17 ms to 150 ms,the time in the client reduces to ~150 ms.

So I tried to send one frame, once the client receive it, it send an acknowledgment and then the server grab the next frame. Using this method the latency was the same ~150 ms.

I'm splitting the data into chunks of an specified size (using 512 bytes at the moment), the client receive the chunks and assembly them, using sha256 I confirmed that the info arrives right, the frames size varies (VBR) from 1200 bytes to 65kb. So my conclusion is that if you stress the socket with a lot of writes the transfer rate get affected, is this right or I may be doing something wrong?

And aside, 150 ms is like 6 fps, how VNC and other streaming apps do it? they buffer some frames and then play them? So there would be a latency but the "experience" would be of a higher frame rate?

Thanks

Comment: They typically all use buffering unless you disable it, and it adds a lot of latency... like half a second or more. Why not transmit larger chunks less frequently? 150 ms is pretty good for video.

Comment: Buffering will help to "smooth out" variations in the latency. Obviously, it won't magically make for more bandwidth, but it will provide smoother playback at the cost of latency. Larger buffers also tend to reduce CPU load, for example in real time audio processing a small buffer could result in dropouts, increasing the buffer can improve that significantly.

Comment: I didn't mean "disable buffering" for the network transfers but for a streaming client. For example, by default VLC will buffer or cache one full second worth of frames before playback begins, obviously that will add a second of latency on top of the stream latency. BTW video streaming usually uses UDP which should give you better latency.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try buffering before switching to UDP, it would be a lot of work getting UDP working properly, I am relying totally on TPC right now.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP/IP protocol stack is free to optimize its behavior to trade off latency vs. bandwidth. You have not demonstrated that you lack the bandwidth, only that you get notified of the arriving data less often that you wish - with there being no technical justification for such wish. There's **nothing** in the protocol itself that guarantees that the data will arrive at the receiving end in chunks of any particular size.

Thus, suppose that you send each frame in a single `write` on the `QIODevice`. The receiving end can receive this data in one or more chunks, and it may receive this data after an arbitrary delay. And that's precisely what you're seeing.

The type of data you're sending has no bearing on performance: you should be able to create a 10-line testcase for the sender, and a similarly sized testcase for the receiver, and confirm that indeed you receive all the data you desire, only it comes in larger chunks than you incorrectly expect. And that's fine and it's normal. To maintain streaming, you should pre-buffer a "sufficient" amount of data at the receiving end.